# Chatting about mathematics (with real-time LaTeX rendering)

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

Do you know about some tools which can be used for online chat about mathematics? In particular, I am interested in software which would be able to render LaTeX formulas. (Since LaTeX is probably the fastest possibility to type mathematics.)

Have you tried some of them? What are their advantages and drawbacks?

NOTE 1: In this question I am asking only about solutions how to type mathematics in chat, not about possibility to use video and sound.
(For the purposes of this question, assume that only keyboard, mouse and display are plugged to your computer.)

NOTE 2: I will post some possibilities I am aware of in the answers. But I would be grateful if someone who tried these applications could expand these answers a little more.

Comment: Some links, which might be relevant: [Tools for long-distance collaboration](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49384/tools-for-long-distance-collaboration) at MO, [Does a Math Chat Application exist that doesn’t require knowlege of LaTeX](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61339/does-a-math-chat-application-exist-that-doesnt-require-knowlege-of-latex) at MO,
[Online physics collaboration tools](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/online-physics-collaboration-tools) from physics.SE, ...

Comment: ... and [Mathematics via Distance Drawing](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories/5621) from Category Theory mailing list.

Comment: Theoretically it might be possible to make your LaTeX-code into pictures and - if the chat client enables this - paste them into chat. It seems that there are [many possibilities](http://www.google.com/#&q=latex+online) how to do this, e.g. [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) online equation editor. But this solution is not so neat and much slower than typing LaTeX code directly into the chat. (I occasionally used such approach to get mathematical formulas into emails.)

Comment: GmailTeX if you use gmail

Comment: "Since LaTeX is probably the fastest possibility to type mathematics" Have you seen ASCIIMathML?

Comment: Maybe https://mathchat.herokuapp.com/chat ?

Answer (score 26):

LaTeX plugin in [Pidgin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin_(software)):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pidgin-latex/

[image: Screenshot 1]

This screenshot is taken from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pidgin-latex/screenshots/124729

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Probably it is better to be called jabber/xmpp + any client that has LaTeX plugin. In addition to pidgin, gajim also have it. Miranda might have one, but not sure.

Answer (score 20):

Mathim - online chat with the possibility to use of LaTeX syntax (the first result that google returned for [latex online chat](http://www.google.com/#&q=latex+online+chat) or [latex online chat math](https://www.google.com/#q=latex+online+chat+math))

http://mathim.com

Screenshot from my short experiment with this tool:

[image: mathim]

Mathim was also discussed here:
http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=193510
http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=196699

<s>It is possible to copy the text of session (simply by selecting it) and put it into a TeX file.</s>

Comment: If some of you have worked with mathim and has some practical experience, I would be glad to know: Is there a possibility to save the text from the session in some way?

Comment: The problem with copying the text of session is solved now. (Before, when I tried to copy the text, the dollars where missing.) http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=3860528

Comment: I've noticed that MathIM has some problems with range in which fonts are valid. E.g. if you write `$(2\mathbb N+1)\cup 2\mathbb N$` then the blackboard font is used for the whole text starting from N. You have to write `$(2{\mathbb N}+1)\cup 2{\mathbb N}$` instead. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/exxIl.png).

Answer (score 19):

[image]

The web interface of [hack.chat](https://hack.chat/) renders LaTeX, and there are some pre-made rooms for math, physics, etc.
It's also open source and can be installed on your own server if needed.

Answer (score 18):

If you use [Discord](https://discordapp.com/), invite [TeXit](https://top.gg/bot/510789298321096704) to your server. (Go to that webpage, click "invite" and enter the name of your server.) Anytime you put dollar signs in a post, TeXit will interpret what you say as LaTeX and will repeat a TeX'd version of what you said. Here is an example of what you'll see

[image]

[Mathbot](https://top.gg/bot/mathbot) is another bot with similar features, but you need to type `=tex` at the start of the line, which I find harder to remember.

Answer (score 14):

**Deprecated:** There are easier ways to render $\LaTeX$ in chat, such as the [start ChatJax](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html)  bookmarklet, which uses [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to render.

In the [Mathematics chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), we often use the codecogs.com $\LaTeX$ Equation Editor: `http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}` yields

[image: \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}]

You have to replace spaces with `%20` since spaces are not allowed in URLs (actually, it is probably best to escape all reserved characters in URLs, but other than spaces, most characters seem to be passed through by a number of common browsers).

Comment: This was most likely true back in 2011 - I suppose that now most people actually use some bookmarklets, like the ones [mentioned in this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support) or on [robjohn's page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html). However, I think that if somebody wanted to try the same bookmarklet for a different chat software, that would most likely require some modifications.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Indeed. I use the "start ChatJax" bookmarklet in chat; I no longer use the codecogs.com page to post $\LaTeX$ in chat. I should edit this post to note its deprecated status.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry for reviving a bit of an old question, however as of today, it is now possible to LaTeX over Facebook chat, automatic rendering. There are a few things to note:

$1:$ You will only be able to view this on desktop, mobile does not support it yet.

$2:$ You must enclose your message in either `\(...\)` for inline math (can be interspersed in text) or `$$...$$` for display math (must be the sole content of a chat message, not recognized if preceded/followed by other text)

$3:$ There is a one-line size limit which isn't terribly generous.

$4:$ If KaTeX can't parse the math, it will stay unrendered text, but you can hover over it to see the error message.

So, a bit restricted, but there's a lot of potential, and the future is now. But yeah, again sorry for mentioning it on such an old message, but I think it's worth letting people know.

Comment: Uses KaTeX.   `$$...$$` gives display math, has to be alone in chat message — doesn't render if there's text before or after for display math.  `\(\displaystyle ...\)` works too.

Comment: Wow this is awesome

Answer (score 9):

Hopefully this is helpful; I have been programming a MathJax based online chat service in my spare time (there are some styling issues still). It is quite fast and has quite a few features. Here it is:

http://mathchat.x10.mx/

Enjoy!

Comment: Is there a possibility to save all messages from a chat session to a file or to clipboard (ideally with leaving TeX intact - so that I can then paste it into a TeX file and compile)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion! I will go about programming that feature in soon. Your suggestion will go on the [current development page](http://mathchat.x10.mx/current-development.php) and I will tell you when it is done.

Comment: Yes, it is now all done. Just use the export chat feature on the bottom right of the chat page and it will give you a TeX document source. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, that was really fast! The exported TeX file and the pdf compiled from it look quite nice.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad that it helps you. I will be introducing optional email notifications soon! Is there anything else that you want to suggest?

Comment: The link is dead…

Comment: @Supermartingale could you please add a new link?

Answer (score 9):

ShareLaTeX had builtin chat with MathJax:

[image: ShareLaTeX chat screenshot]

UPDATE: it was aquired by Overleaf.  As almost all of ShareLaTeX, it was open source, and remains open source after aquisition!
Source moved here: [[backend](https://github.com/overleaf/chat), [frontend](https://github.com/overleaf/web/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chat)].

As of 2020 it's integrated into [Overleaf.com](https://overleaf.com), and all MathJax features seem to work fine:

[image: Overleaf chat screenshot]

This is a near-real-time collaborative LaTeX editor, so this is great for chatting around a writeup/paper, but you can also create empty project or file just to use chat/commenting, and gradually "spill over" into the editor for a more flexible collaboration...

P.S. Note that for review comments on particular points of the paper, Overleaf have [dedicated feature](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Track_Changes_in_Overleaf) for comment threads on particular points!  These don't render math currently.
[image: Oveleaf review panel]

Answer (score 8):

I work on [Zulip](https://zulipchat.com/), an open source team chat server.  It supports LaTeX using `$$…$$` for inline math and

````
```math
…
```
````

for displayed math.  These are rendered on the server side using [KaTeX](https://katex.org/).

Comment: I wonder why don't you use `$...$` for inline math, just as Markdown.

Comment: @Akira There is no LaTeX in “Markdown”, neither in the [original implementation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) nor the [CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/). It’s always an extension, and the various extensions for LaTeX are not consistent with each other. They’re not even consistent within the Stack Exchange network: [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607) Stack Exchange sites use `\$…\$`, some use `$…$`, some don’t support it at all. See [this issue](https://github.com/zulip/zulip/issues/16367) for some of the considerations involved in Zulip.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** This project seems to be abandoned. (At least the website does not work anymore.) If anyone has the knowledge that it has been moved to another location, please, edit this post with updated information.

[TeXChat](http://texchat.juanbb.com/) is a chat which uses Mathjax for rendering math.

I've learned about it from the website [MathJax in Use](http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/).

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can copy a source of an individual message by hovering above it and selecting the text.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how the source of the whole session can be copied. I you find out, please, let me know. (And maybe add this to the answer.)

Comment: I [asked the author about that several months ago](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49384/tools-for-long-distance-collaboration/86719#86719) and had not received a response.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/jbenet/TeXchat/issues/1) it seems that he was planning to do this. (Hopefully, he still is.)

Comment: Seems abandoned, site is currently down

Answer (score 6):

There are scripts written by [Valery Alexeev](http://alexeev.org/display-latex2.html).

UPDATE: The new name for this plugin is [TeX for Gmail](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html). Now there is only one plugin which adds TeX-rendering to both Gmail and Gmail Chat. (IIRC, they used to be separate.)

---

Here is original version of this post:

They were mentioned in this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/online-physics-collaboration-tools/7811#7811

[GmailTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html) was mentioned in [leo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8271/leo)'s comment. There is also [GmailChatTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailchattex.html).

---

This Firefox add-on http://thewe.net/tex/ seems to be similar.

Comment: Again, any comment by someone who actually tried some of these would be great.

Comment: TeX for Gmail is great, especially ability to heuristically recognize and render in *incoming unformatted mail* stuff like `A_n` without explicit math delimiters.  Worked fine in chat too but doesn't (yet) support Hangouts.

Answer (score 5):

[Gitter](https://gitter.im) which is generally programmer-optimized (markdown, syntax highlight, GitHub integration) also [supports math with `$$...$$` syntax](http://blog.gitter.im/2014/09/16/maths-geeks-take-note/):

(OUTDATED screenshot)
[image: outdated screenshot]

---

### UPDATE(2024): They'd [switched to Matrix protocol](https://blog.gitter.im/2023/02/13/gitter-has-fully-migrated-to-matrix/)

IIUC math support is now up to individual client software one uses?  There is [a spec proposal](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-spec-proposals/pull/2191).

- https://app.gitter.im/ is a form of Element Web which [supports KaTeX rendering](https://github.com/element-hq/element-web/issues/1945) using `\(inline\)` and

  ```
  \[
  display
  \]
  ```

  syntaxes, plus `$` and `$$` aliases:
  [image: app.gitter.im screenshot]
- The proposal says Element Android and Cinny clients also implement it. (didn't test)
- One other desktop client — Neochat — I tested on same room, and it didn't render the math...

Answer (score 5):

If you want a wide platform support, including smartphones and want a mainstream messenger lots of people already use, then **telegram** with a latex bot can do this. If you are not familiar with telegram, it's basically like whatsapp.

Once you have telegram, you need to add a bot (just a contact) that would render LaTeX to image in your chats. Right now I have inlatexbot, but there are also others. https://github.com/vdrhtc/InLaTeXbot

It might not be as feature reach and perfect as latex plugins for jabber clients, for example, it is not capable of inline math, it just gives you an image with your formula in chat. If you need LaTeX only occasionally, this is ok.

However, I believe telegram is the only mainstream messenger that can do LaTeX and it is also available for all major platforms including mobile. It also has a superfast synchronization between your devices via cloud (yes, you can store your history on the server).

Answer (score 4):

Instabird with [this MathJax addon](https://addons.instantbird.org/en-US/instantbird/addon/340):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

http://papertogether.com is a collaborative whiteboard app with chat that supports math surrounded by backticks:

```
Foo `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` bar baz.
```

Unfortunately there is no text tool to add  formulas inside the drawing area, and the chat is a small subwindow in the corner.

KaTeX-powered so supports less constructs (e.g. no matrices).
[Help](http://papertogether.com/home/help), [Background](http://papertogether.com/home/about)

Comment: Meanwhile KaTeX added support for arrays: `\left ( \begin{array}{lcr}
Aa & B & C\\
D & Ee & Ff
\end{array} \right)`. (paste that in http://khan.github.io/KaTeX to see the output)

Comment: The link isn't working. Did they move? Is there an alternative Collaborative White Board?

Answer (score 2):

I use Lyx to type LaTeX quickly. It is a WYSIWYG LaTeX editor.
You can then use screen sharing e.g with Skype so the other person can see what you are doing on Lyx. 
Never tried the screen sharing part, just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

[Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) has a 'Chat' feature which is accessible in the top-right corner and is LaTeX-processed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the easiest answer: Facebook Messager! If you write a message of the form:

`$$ equation here $$`

The whole message has to be only the formula, if you want an equation as a part of a longer message you can use:

`Some text \( equation here \) and more text.`

[image]

Comment: Only works on desktop version though, but I'd be surprised if you wanted to do it on your phone.

Comment: If I understood correctly what I read [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/6ug91z/facebook_messenger_now_renders_basic_latex/), if you want to use equation as a prat of the linger message, you have to use `\(....\)` rather than `$$...$$`, double dollars only work if the message contains nothing else. I have edited your post to reflect this - feel free to edit it further if more details are needed.

Comment: Only now I noticed that this is already mentioned in the [answer posted by Daminark](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering/2397727#2397727).

Answer (score 1):

I use overleaf and screenshare it while talking over zoom. Or I use a chrome extension "TeX for Gmail & Inbox"