# What is a good communication platform, which supports something like TeX-code?

Tags: soft-question, learning, online-resources

I moved away and am now planning to communicate with a friend over the internet and talk about mathematical subjects (e.g. via Skype). However the text blocks like "\int_G\omega..." in a chat window become more or less unreadable. It would be helpful to have a script like here on StackExchange, which translates the formulas.

> Is there a good web page where one can write TeX code such that the other person sees changes live, or at least after pressing F5?

Comment: There is [GmailTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html), and an associated "plug-in" for Gmail Chat.  I've only ever used the plain GmailTeX, but it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Or consider chat with screen sharing; I don't know if.Skype has it but Google+ hangout does. This can be used either  in combination with TeX processing software on your end, or (with a stylus and touch screen) to hand-write the formulas.

Comment: This question (and also some links mentioned in the comments there) might be interesting for you: [Chatting about mathematics (with real-time LaTeX rendering)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering/).

Comment: You might also find something useful at TeX.SE, see e.g. [Simultaneous collaborative editing of a LaTeX file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/simultaneous-collaborative-editing-of-a-latex-file)
and [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online).

Answer (score 1):

When I need it, I use [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) - there is a bit of lag, but overall it works.