# MathJax (or something like it) as a classroom "blackboard"

Tags: education

At the risk of possible overlap with this (9-month-old) question

[Chatting about mathematics (with real-time LaTeX rendering)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering)

what is the best desktop application now for running MathJax in the classroom.

I can't depend on having a connection to the web, so I'm seeking a stand-alone application.
To be clear, I'd like to type as I talk and have the students see the typeset mathematics with as small a delay as possible.  (An application's waiting for the ends of paragraphs might be a deal breaker.)

Comment: I think the mathjax website might be of more help than math.SE.

Comment: I have indeed looked there, but I'd really like to hear from a flesh-and-blood teacher who actually does this...to avoid bugs, programs that hang-up, etc.  And of course if MathJax has a competitor, I won't find that out there.

Comment: Just tried Qute, which would do in a pinch.  It has competitors.

Comment: Just tried Pidgin, but couldn't figure out how to make it see the TeX plugin or function as a Blackboard if I'm not actually using it for chat.

Comment: I use asciimath a lot for personal notetaking. It definitely satisfies your requirement of no delay. You can type and see the results live: http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimathdemo.html Although it runs in a browser, I believe it doesn't require a live web connection. I think you can just install the javascript locally on your laptop or whatever.