# Approximating a blackboard with long-distance communication

Tags: soft-question, math-software

From time to time I need to talk about mathematics with my advisor remotely. I would like to approximate writing on a blackboard together as closely as is reasonable. What are some technological options I have for doing this?

It would be nice to do something similar to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbCZbP6_j48, though it would be much better if it can also be done in realtime.

Edit: This question was edited in order to meet the exacting demands of the MSE Community Standards. I have borrowed a suggested phrasing from [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/closing-a-question-because-of-legalism).

Comment: Have a look at
[Tools for long-distance collaboration](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49384/tools-for-long-distance-collaboration) at MO,
[Online physics collaboration tools](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/online-physics-collaboration-tools) from physics.SE,
and [Mathematics via Distance Drawing](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories/5621) from Category Theory mailing list.
I've copied those links from comments to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering).

Comment: Once I've heard a talk about this project: [Media Spaces and Video in the Home](http://carmster.com/clab/index.php?n=Main.Media_Spaces_and_Video_in_the_Home) at the Simon Fraser University, Canada. It featured a screen on which both parties were able to write text to be visible by both parties. Some screenshots may be seen on [slides here](http://carmster.com/clab/uploads/Main/ConnectingFamilies.pdf). Maybe something like that could be applicable in your case?

Comment: A similar question was posted today on [Ask Slashdot](http://ask.slashdot.org/story/15/02/28/067243/ask-slashdot-whiteboard-substitutes-for-distributed-teams?utm_source=slashdot&utm_medium=twitter)

Answer (score 0):

One option is Fluidmath. I've used it quite a bit over the last 3 years and it's come in handy. There are quite a few videos on YouTube on how you can use it!

https://www.fluidmath.net/login?came_from=%2Fhome%2F